# Overlapping background Graphics in a Memory Game Applet

Tags: java, swing, japplet, mouselistener

Okay I have been working on this memory game applet in java for a while now and I have all the sorting and matching algorithms all figured out, I am just having a wretched time trying to get my GUI to function properly.  Whenever I click on one of the "cards" to "flip", I end up with a column of the cards being created while their backs counterparts remain under the cards until you go over it with the cursor.  It is all very frustrating as I am not quite sure why half of this is happening or how to stop it.  Here is my Display class:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Polygon;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Display extends JPanel implements MouseListener {

private String[] Colors = Card.validColors();
private String[] Shapes = Card.validShapes();
private Component[] place;
private JButton[][] buttonGrid= new JButton[6][6];
private Rectangle[][] triggers = new Rectangle[6][6];
private Board game;
private Polygon star = new Polygon();
private Card pick;
private boolean turnPhase2 = false;
private Font serifNames = new Font(Font.SERIF, Font.PLAIN, 18);
private Font serifCards = new Font(Font.SERIF, Font.ROMAN_BASELINE, 36);
private JPanel panel = new JPanel();

public Display() {
    this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    panel.setSize(590, 410);
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(6, 6, 10, 10));
    panel.setOpaque(false);

    generateStar();
    buildBoard();
    fillButtonArray();

    this.addMouseListener(this);
    this.add(panel);
    System.out.println(getFontMetrics(serifCards));
    System.out.println(getFontMetrics(serifNames));
}



public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    place = panel.getComponents();
    for (int i = 0; i < place.length; i++) {
        paintBack(g, place[i].getX() + 25, place[i].getY() + 35);
    }
    displayNames(g);
    displayTurn(g);
    if (game.flippedCard() != null) {
        int[] xy = game.flippedCardLocation();
        paintCard(g, game.flippedCard(), xy[0], xy[1]);
    }
}

/**
 * This method builds the game board.
 * 
 * 
 */
private void buildBoard() {
    game = new Board(buildDeck());
}

/**
 * This method creates a "deck" of cards with which we can create the game board.
 * 
 * @return deck Returns the deck of Card objects in the form of an ArrayList.
 */
private ArrayList<Card> buildDeck() {
    ArrayList<Card> deck = new ArrayList<Card>();

    for (int i = 0; i < Colors.length; i++) {
        for (int s = 0; s < Shapes.length; s++) {
            Card first = new Card(Shapes[s], Colors[i]);
            Card second = new Card(Shapes[s], Colors[i]);
            deck.add(first);
            deck.add(second);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(deck.size());
    return deck;
}

private void fillButtonArray() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        for (int n = 0; n < 6; n++) {
            JButton button = new JButton();
            button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(90, 60));
            button.addMouseListener(this);
            button.setOpaque(false);
            button.setContentAreaFilled(false);
            button.setBorderPainted(false);

            buttonGrid[i][n] = button;
        }
    }
    fillGrid();
}

private void fillGrid() {
    panel.setBounds(25, 35, panel.getSize().width, panel.getSize().height);
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        for (int s = 0; s < 6; s++) {
            panel.add(buttonGrid[i][s]);
            place = panel.getComponents();
            int x = panel.getComponent(count).getBounds().x;
            int y = panel.getComponent(count).getBounds().y;
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(x, y, 90, 60);
            triggers[i][s] = rect;
        }
    }

}

private void paintBack(Graphics g, int x, int y) {
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.drawRoundRect(x, y, 90, 60, 2, 4);
    g.fillRoundRect(x, y, 90, 60, 2, 4);
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.setFont(serifCards);
    g.drawString("M", x + 28, y + 42);
}

private void paintCard(Graphics g, Card card, int x, int y) {
    g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
    g.drawRoundRect(x, y, 90, 60, 2, 4);
    g.fillRoundRect(x, y, 90, 60, 2, 4);
    String color = card.getColor();
    String shape = card.getShape();

    if (shape.equals("Star")) {
        g.setColor(pickColor(color));
        star.translate(x + 25, y + 10);
        g.drawPolygon(star);
        g.fillPolygon(star);

    }
    else if (shape.equals("Circle")) {
        g.setColor(pickColor(color));
        g.drawOval(x + 25, y + 10, 40, 40);
        g.fillOval(x + 25, y + 10, 40, 40);
    }
    else if (shape.equals("Square")) {
        g.setColor(pickColor(color));
        g.drawRect(x + 25, y + 10, 40, 40);
        g.fillRect(x + 25, y + 10, 40, 40);
    }
}



private void displayNames(Graphics g) {
    g.setFont(serifNames);
    int[] scores = game.getCurrentScores();

    for (int i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
            g.setColor(Color.CYAN);
            g.drawString("Cyan: " + scores[i], 10, 24);
        }
        else if (i == 1) {
            g.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
            g.drawString("Orange: " + scores[i], 560, 24);
        }
        else if (i == 2) {
            g.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
            g.drawString("Magenta: " + scores[i], 10, 470);
        }
        else {
            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g.drawString("White: " + scores[i], 569, 470);
        }
    }
}

private void displayTurn(Graphics g) {
    int player = game.getCurrentPlayer();

    if (player == 0) {
        g.setColor(Color.CYAN);
        String str = "Cyan's Turn";
        g.drawString(str, 640 / 2 - 48, 24);
        //System.out.println(getFontMetrics(serifNames).stringWidth(str) / 2 + " Cyan");
    }
    else if (player == 1) {
        g.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
        String str = "Orange's Turn";
        g.drawString(str, 640 / 2 - 52, 24);
        //System.out.println(getFontMetrics(serifNames).stringWidth(str) / 2 + " Orange");
    }
    else if (player == 2) {
        g.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
        String str = "Magenta's Turn";
        g.drawString(str, 640 / 2 - 57, 24);
        //System.out.println(getFontMetrics(serifNames).stringWidth(str) / 2 + " Magenta");
    }
    else {
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        String str = "White's Turn";
        g.drawString(str, 640 / 2 - 47, 24);
        //System.out.println(getFontMetrics(serifNames).stringWidth(str) / 2 + " White");
    }
}

private void findTrigger(int x, int y) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        if () {

        }
        for (int s = 0; s < 6; s++) {
            Rectangle rectTest = triggers[i][s];
            if (x >= rectTest.getMinX() &&
                    x <= rectTest.getMaxX() &&
                    y >= rectTest.getMinY() &&
                    y <= rectTest.getMaxY()) {
                Graphics g = getGraphics();
                paintCard(g, game.flip(i,s), buttonGrid[i][s].getBounds().x, buttonGrid[i][s].getBounds().y);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

private void generateStar() {
    star.addPoint(20, 0);
    star.addPoint(25, 15);
    star.addPoint(40, 15);
    star.addPoint(28, 24);
    star.addPoint(32, 40);
    star.addPoint(20, 30);
    star.addPoint(8, 40);
    star.addPoint(12, 24);
    star.addPoint(0, 15);
    star.addPoint(15, 15);
}

private Color pickColor(String color) {
    if (color.equals("Black")) {
        return Color.BLACK;
    }
    if (color.equals("Yellow")) {
        return Color.YELLOW;
    }
    if (color.equals("Green")) {
        return Color.GREEN;
    }
    if (color.equals("Blue")) {
        return Color.BLUE;
    }
    if (color.equals("Red")) {
        return Color.RED;
    }
    if (color.equals("Purple")) {
        return new Color(128, 0, 255);
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    System.out.println("Mouse Clicked");
    int x = e.getX();
    System.out.println(x + " is x");
    int y = e.getY();
    System.out.println(y + " is Y");
    System.out.println(panel.getWidth() + 25);
    System.out.println(panel.getHeight() + 35);

    System.out.println("Finding the trigger rectangle");
    findTrigger(x, y);
}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    //System.out.println("Mouse Entered");
}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    //System.out.println("Mouse Exited");
}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    System.out.println("Mouse Pressed");
}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    System.out.println("Mouse Released");
}
```

}

Some side notes is that the actual game is handled by the board object and has all the methods needed to create and run a multiplayer memory game and the Card object only contains two strings of the shape and color of what is to be matched by the game.  And finally the last class is the Memory class which I will provide:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.JApplet;

public class Memory extends JApplet {
private Display _theDisplay;
final int width = 640;
final int height = 480;

private Action reDraw = new AbstractAction() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        repaint();
    }
};

public Memory() {
    _theDisplay = new Display();
}

public void init() {
    setSize(width, height);
    setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    this.add(_theDisplay);
}

}
```

Please any tips would be incredibly helpful, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Your graphics appear messed. Problems I see:

- You call `getGraphics()` on a component to draw with its Graphics context, but please understand that a Graphics object obtained in this way will not persist, and can thus mess up or even cause a NPE to be thrown.
- Better to do all-passive Graphics via your `paintComponent(...)` method. If you need any pre-made drawings, do these in BufferedImages, and draw the BufferedImages in the JComponent's `paintComponent(...)` method.
- Rather than have your Display JPanel do all the painting of the cards and the backs, I suggest that each Card be its own separate object with its own state, that paints itself correctly depending on its state. You may wish to have this extend a JComponent, or have it be a logical entity that is then painted by your Display JPanel, up to you, but separate out the logic from the display to simplify your coding and debugging.
- A major problem looks to be in your `findTrigger(...)` method and that is where you should concentrate your efforts. You should use the mouseClick to change the state of the logical Card (as described above) that is clicked and then call `repaint()` on the Display JPanel (this) if the Cards are painted in `paintComponent(...)`.
- Else if the Cards paint themselves, consider having them be JLabels and simply swap ImageIcons, likely the easiest way to "flip" cards.
- Your main problem is that of a program mis-behavior. I have not seen the cause of this on a quick overview of your code, and suggest that you use a debugger or println statements to first and foremost try to isolate the problem.

Comment: I figured out what the problem was.  I have the invisible JPanel panel which houses a full 2d array of JButtons.  The buttons have their own listeners so whenever someone clicks on any of the buttons, the if statement is immediately proven correct because the X and Y of the MouseClicker is considered a whole other panel on its' own.  You definitely pointed me in the right direction mate.  Cheers!

Comment: @Dusquad: glad you've got things going in the right direction!